# jekyll build hook to create gz versions of each .html file

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

Does `jekyll build` provide a hook which I can use to `gzip` each .html file in the `_site` directory? I'd like to have a corresponding `example.html.gz` file to an `example.html` file.

I would write a wrapper script in case there is no hook. I just want to be sure to make it in the cleanest way possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hook in `jekyll build`.
The only way to generate additional content is to write a [generator plugin](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#generators).

If your goal is to serve the gzipped version of you pages, you must know that github pages already serves gzipped html, css and js.

Comment: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#generators says "Generators run after Jekyll has made an inventory of the existing content, and before the site is generated." So I can't use it for this.

Comment: Of course you can. The inventory is in memory and all pages datas are available. You just have to loop in the collection, get the rendered content, gzip and save your page.html.gzip. That's less than 20 lines of code.